# Can I check what the macro was defined in pre-compile?

Tags: c, macros, precompile

```
#define STR_A  abc
#if STR_A == abc   //I want to make some check here
    do something A
#else
    do something B
#endif
```

Can I check what the STR_A defined?

Comment: Have you actually tried what you wrote?

Comment: I just write some demo code to express my meaning. I only want to check what the macro STR_A defined .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if `STR_A` is defined to the token `abc` (which by itself shouldn't be another macro) you can help yourself with some tricks

```
#define STR_A_TESTER_abc 1
#define CONCAT(A, B) A ## B
#define STR_A_TESTER CONCAT(STR_A_TESTER_, STR_A)

#if STR_A_TESTER
// do whatever
#else
// or other
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

That happens quite a lot when trying to distinguish operating systems.

The same can be used for your **STR_A**.

```c
#if defined(STR_A)
#  if (STR_A == "abc")
    // do something
#  else
    // do something else
#  endif
#else
  #warning "STR_A has not been defined."
#endif
```

Comment: the preprocessor isn't able to handle strings, so what your are proposing doen't work at all

Comment: Oh of course I forgot about that.  The OS macros are integers.